# React Native error while updating property 'accessibiltyRole' of a view etc. in createMaterialTopTabNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am getting this error after running my App:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnUzH.jpg)
I don't know what I am doing wrong here, I had tried to change another version of lib but not solve my problem. Please check my code:

```
import { createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from "react-navigation-tabs";

const SurveyTabRoutes = createMaterialTopTabNavigator(
  {
    "Profil Singkat": DetailCalonPeminjam,
    "Data Survei": DataSurveiPeminjam
  },
  {
    tabBarOptions: {
      style:{backgroundColor:"#E5E5E5"},
      activeTintColor: '#009666',
      inactiveTintColor: 'rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.5)',
      labelStyle: {
          lineHeight:22,
          fontSize: 15,
          fontFamily:"Poppins-Medium"
        },
        upperCaseLabel: false,
        indicatorStyle:{backgroundColor:"#009666"}
    },
  }
);

export default createAppContainer(SurveyTabRoutes);
```

i'm using these version of libs :

---

1. "react-native-reanimated": "^1.7.0",
2. "react-native-safe-area-view": "^1.0.0",
3. "react-native-screens": "^2.0.0-alpha.29",
4. "react-navigation": "^4.0.9",
5. "react-navigation-stack": "^1.9.0",
6. "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.7.0",
7. "react": "16.8.3",
8. "react-native": "0.59.0",

---

Comment: Upgrade your React Native version

Comment: i'm not really sure to upragde my react-native version, because the project requirement's have to use version under 60 @satya164

Answer (score 0):

Please define your tab navigator as below :

```js
const SurveyTabRoutes = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
    ProfilSingkat: {
      screen: DetailCalonPeminjam
    },
    DataSurvei: {
      screen: DataSurveiPeminjam
    }
  },{
    tabBarOptions: {
      style:{backgroundColor:"#E5E5E5"},
      activeTintColor: '#009666',
      inactiveTintColor: 'rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.5)',
      labelStyle: {
        lineHeight:22,
        fontSize: 15,
        fontFamily:"Poppins-Medium"
      },
      upperCaseLabel: false,
      indicatorStyle:{backgroundColor:"#009666"}
    },
  }
);

export default createAppContainer(SurveyTabRoutes);
```

Comment: thx bro, but it still produces the same problem @Kishan Bharda